# How to configure Spring lookup-method with Spring property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to inject a property everytime a bean (myBean) is called using a lookup method and Spring dependency injection :

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.myclass"
        <property name="default" ref="myDefault" >
            <lookup-method name="getUri" bean="defaultUri" />
        </property>
</bean>
    <bean id="defaultUri" scope="prototype" class="DefaultUri" >        
    </bean>

class myclass {
 public String getUri(){
    return "test"
 }
}
```

Above XML returns this error on startup :

"XML document from PortletContext resource is invalied"

The error seems to be because `<lookup-method name="getUri" bean="defaultUri" />` is configured incorrectly.

How can I configure a Spring lookup method within a String 'property' as I'm trying to implement in above XML ?

Comment: Did you try defining the defaultUri bean above myBean in your xml?

Comment: @Keerthi Ramanathan yes ive tried that but same error

Comment: Please post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lookup method injection is the ability of the container to override methods on container managed beans, to return the lookup result for another named bean in the container.

Now, suppose you want to get a new instance of `DefaultUri` (which is a prototype bean) every time you call a method (let it be `createDefaultUri`) in `myclass` (which is a singleton bean). Then you can define `MyClass` as this:

```
class abstract Myclass {
 public String getUri(){
    // create a new instance of DefaultUri
    DefaultUri defaultUri = createDefaultUri();
    return "test"
 }

 protected abstract DefaultUri createDefaultUri();
}
```

The Spring Framework will generate a dynamic subclass of `Myclass` that will override the `createDefaultUri` method to provide a new instance of `DefaultUri` every time it is requested for.

You can now define the name of `lookup-method` name in the `Myclass` bean definition as this:

```
<bean id="defaultUri" scope="prototype" class="DefaultUri">
</bean>

<bean id="myBean" class="com.myclass"
        <lookup-method name="createDefaultUri" bean="defaultUri" />
</bean>
```

Comment: the method  "getUri" now seems redundant as it is not used ?

Comment: yes.. i just kept it there because it was there in the question :). if it is not needed you can of course remove it and wherever you want a new instance of `DefaultUri`, you just need to call `createDefaultUri()`.

Comment: thanks but how can I refer to that method using the Spring <property> tag ?

Comment: that cannot be done and i don't think there is a need for that. Because the properties will be set only once for your singleton bean and if you define your prototype bean as a property of singleton bean, it will be set only once. So even if `DefaultUri` is a prototype bean, you will get only a single instance of it. And this is not what you want. So to get a new instance of `DefaultUri` every time, you need to use `createDefaultUri()` method for that. So that, even if `MyClass` is singleton, you can obtain a new instance of `DefaultUri` wherever you want.

Comment: apologies but im very confused by this. A new instance of DefaultUri is returned everytime but it seems I have no control to provide the implementation of the DefaultUri since Spring generates a subclass which will override createDefaultUri. What if instead of returning a DefaultUri I was returning a String, I would want to configure what String should be returned but it seems this is handled by the Spring container somehow ?

Comment: As the first line of my answer says that lookup method returns `another named bean in the container`. So the instance it returns should be a spring managed bean. You can create a class `DefaultUri` and define it as just another spring managed bean, which you are already doing. Now, every time you call `createDefaultUri`, spring will provide you with a new instance of `DefaultUri`. Even if you were allowed to return a new String from the lookup method, it would always return a new String with same value, which is same as returning the same String.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose singleton bean A needs to use non-singleton (prototype) bean B, perhaps on each method invocation on A(getBeanB()), we expect to get new instance of bean B for every request. But The container only creates the singleton bean A once, and thus only gets one opportunity to set the properties. The container cannot provide bean A with a new instance of bean B every time one is needed.  To get new new instance of bean B for every request we need to use lookup-method injection

Please refer to http://www.javapointer.com/spring/spring-core/spring-lookup-method-injection/

Comment: Link is dead; it is archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20161205180420/http://www.javapointer.com/spring/spring-core/spring-lookup-method-injection/